# QT - How to add a button over a scrollArea (with absolute position)

Tags: c++, qt5, qt-designer

I have the following layout

[image]

What I'm trying to do here it's to place a custom widget (the BLUE one) over a scrollArea.

Here it's how looks my outline:

[image]

And I would like to add that BLUE widget between `home_page` and `scrollArea` in terms of the outline, or other words in terms of GUI I would like to add that button over `ScrollAreaContent` BUT I don't want to move that button from its position at the moment when I'm moving the `ScrollAreaContent`.

```
auto sizeX = 0.25 * w;
auto sizeY = 0.9 * h;

ui->scrollArea->setBaseSize(w,h);
ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->setBaseSize(w,h);

ui->home_page->layout()->setMargin(0);
ui->home_page->layout()->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout());
ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->layout()->setMargin(0);
ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->layout()->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

//This list is going to contain the buttons from scrollAreaWidgetContents
auto buttons = new QList<MenuHomeButton *>();  

//...
//ADD buttons
//...

ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);


for (auto button : *buttons) {
    ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->layout()->addWidget(button);
    connect(button, SIGNAL(buttonClicked(int)), ui->stackedWidget, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
}
QScroller::grabGesture(ui->scrollArea, QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);
```

Does any of you have any idea how can I do this?

Comment: maybe one way to do it is as suggested by Pablo. Make the blue widget as child and move/update its position every time you scroll horizontally. It would give an illusion of blue widget  as fixed in its place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to position a widget by yourself, you must not add it to a layout.

You can create the widget as child widget of your container and then call the show method on it. That way the new widget will be at position (0,0) relative to the container (of course you can move it wherever you want).
You can still have a layout in the container for managing other widgets, ie: the scrollarea.

I think in your case you could do something like:

```
auto but=new QPushButton(ui->scrollAreaWidget);
but->show();
```

Also I strongly recommend you not to use designer when your are planning to do this, in my experience it is more clear.